# Evenly distribute Plot Co-ordinates onto a shape in 2D and 3D - For use in Prezi/Jmpress.js

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, dictionary, geometry

I am trying to plot X/Y and/or X/Y/Z coordinates for a set of items so that they can be laid out in a particular shape.

My goal:  Create and position Slides so that they can be placed onto a presentation canvas as a particular shape. The canvas will be like Prezi (I'm going to be doing this with Jmpress.js).

Examples could be as follow

**2D or X/Y examples**

- 8 Slide in the shape of a Circle
- 4 Slides in the shape of a rectangle or square
- 6 Slides in the shape of a 6 point diamond
- 10 Slides on the outline of a Shape such as a Face, Dog, Computer etc...

**3D or X/Y/Z examples**

- 15 Slides in the shape of a Double Helix
- 6 Slides in the shape of a Cube

I'm not sure how to do the mathematics to make this happen.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

For a circle you can split it up by angle. So you want slides at 0, 90, 180, 270, 306 and then quarter angles, at 30, 60, 120, 150, 210, 240, 300, 330... Then the 2D positions would be

(x,y) = (r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta))... then if you want them to be integers... I'd just floor them.

For the rest, you're going to need to use a set of functions.